# 414 error while trying to access my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am getting 414 error requested URI too large while trying to access my wordpress website. I am unable to access the site from the browser on which the error occured.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Apache`, there is a variable called `LimitRequestLine`
The default value is 8190 and you can change this configuration

The value is in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`but you can also try to add`LimitRequestLine 10000 `in`AccessFileName .htaccess` ( depending on host permissions)

However, that being said - if you really need such long `URI` there is a good chance that your site ( plugin, theme ) is using `GET` request the wrong way ( instead of `POST` for example..

I would recommend you to disable plugins and themes, and then activate them one by one to find the culprit, then see if there is any way to fix the issue. it is sometimes caused by using `jQuery` `$.getJSON()` for example or similar `GET` requests..